# Find smallest vectors in submodule of $\mathbb{Z}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, modules

I have a $\mathbb{Z}$ submodule in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ given by a basis. I'm trying to get the smallest elements, where the norm used for smallest is not very important, lets say $\ell^1$ or $\ell^\infty$.

Why I'm doing this is to compute all solutions of $Ax=b$ with $A$ a matrix with only one row which has only positive entry's and $b$ a positive number. I have to do this for the same $A$ for a lot of $b$'s.

I think that this is not a problem which has a really good algorithm but I hope that there is something better than what I'm doing.

now I fix a bound for the coefficients and for the vector entry's and then I brute force check all linear combinations.

Another way I used to do it, is to order $A$ and to compute the maximum of every entry of $x$ and then go trough each possible $x$. This gives for only one $b$ the fastest answer but when I have to compute it for several $b$'s it's super slow.

Comment: A linear subspace passes through the origin, so the smallest vector it contains in *any* norm is zero. Do you mean an affine subspace, perhaps?

Comment: How can a linear *subspace* being inside a non-linear vector space like $\;\Bbb Z^n\;$ ? Perhaps you mean a subgroup?

Comment: To the first question I'm looking for the smallest elements in the sense like the 10 smallest elements not all smallest elements with the same norm. For the second I just realized that I didn't translate it right. The correct term is subgroup

Comment: Actually the norm is important to the algorithm, so I'm having difficulty parsing your last Comment.  Are you saying you would be happy with finding the smallest vectors with whatever norm makes the problem easiest to solve?

Comment: Yeah thats what I tryed to say that whoever has a solution using any norm is welcome